# Can we use other database with wamp

Tags: wamp

Can we use other database like oracle with WAMP package? Or if I want to use PHP,oracle and apache to use then can I do this? How?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes.

PHP has support for connecting to Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS-SQL, and various others. You just have to have the PHP extension installed for the database you wish to use.

Comment: And also if I am using WAMP package so is it necessary that I have o use apache ,php,and mysql all the three together?? Can't I use php and apache and make connectivity with oracle, using apache and php of WAMPpackage

Comment: WAMP is not a package - it refers to a set of tools used to create a database-driven web application. As I already answered, yes, you can use other databases. Also, as Mike pointed out, it would not be "WAMP", as that assumes use of a MySQL database, but Oracle and other databases can be used in place of MySQL, assuming you have the PHP extension installed allowing you to access that particular database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. You can access the Oracle DB from PHP, but then it won't be called WAMP anymore.

Comment: hmm ... WAOP instead of WAMP?

Comment: I was making a (apparently non-witty) comment ... there is no such thing, to my knowledge, as "WAOP". Also, please see my other comment regarding the use of the term "package".

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Oracle instead of MySQL follow this link and it will work more than fine and don't bother your self by knowing what will it be called as someone before said:

https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/connect-wamp-server-to-oracle-with-php-php_oci8_11g-dll

this link contain every thing you want I did those things and it is working gooood for me. The wamp will still be called wamp all the difference is that you will be using Oracle instead of MySQL. ;)